# Placing a div inside bootstrap column pushes content to new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having a text message wrapped in bootstrap column div and i'm trying to customize specific text in that column by wrapping it with another div but bootstrap pushes that text to a new line.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
             Text1
         </div>
         <div class="col">Text2<div>Text3</div></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e642tsb1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because `div` has a default property of `display: block;` which makes the `div` appear in a new line. Use the bootstrap class `d-inline-block` to set its `display: inline-block;`

It will then appear in the same line.

```css
.row {
  background: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Text1
    </div>
    <div class="col">Text2
      <div class="d-inline-block">Text3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your interior `div` to a `span` and it will appear on the same line:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
             Text1
         </div>
         <div class="col">Text2 <span>Text3</span></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

A `div` is a block level element by default, meaning its content will take the entire width of the page, so any child `div` will do the same. Here is your updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2huy04kc/

Answer (score 1):

That's true it will happen.

`<div> Text2 </div>` will push your `<div> Text3 </div>` to the next line as div are `block` elements.

> A **block-level element** always starts on a new line and takes up the
>   full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it
>   can).

Better you use `<span></span>` or give a `display: inline-block;` property to the inner `div` containing *Text3*.

Learn different types of display in CSS [*here*](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/).

Answer (score 0):

The div element is a block-level element. A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available. You can use span element as an inline element. An inline element does not start on a new line and only takes up as much width as necessary.

Solution 1 : Replace div element with span element

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
             Text1
         </div>
         <div class="col">Text2<span>Text3</span></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Solution 2 : Styling div element to display as an inline element (not recommended).

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
             <div class="col">
                 Text1
             </div>
             <div class="col">Text2<div style="display:inline">Text3</div></div>
         </div>
    </div>
```